# Correlation matrix from pairwise correlations with specified structure

Tags: correlation, covariance-matrix, random-generation, multivariate-normal-distribution

I need to simulate multivariate normal samples with a pre-specified correlation structure. The structure is such that the bigger the (GPS) distance between two points, the smaller the correlation (with some random noise). I'm having issues enforcing this property and, at the same time, making sure the resulting correlation matrix is positive semidefinite. Is there a good way to do this?

To give a more concrete example: I'd like the pairwise correlation to drop relatively smoothly from 1 to 0 (or slightly below 0) as the distance between the two points goes from 0 km to 1,000 km. If the distance is greater than 1,000 km, the correlation should be, again, close to 0. So far I've been using a portion of the sine curve (something like $\rho=1-\text{sin}(0.0011x) + \epsilon$, where $x$ is the distance in km and $\epsilon$ the random noise component) to calculate the pairwise correlations, but I've found that it does not guarantee that the resulting correlation matrix will be positive semidefinite. The points I'm looking at are distributed relatively evenly across the continental US and Europe.

Comment: What you are looing for is a [covariance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#Covariance_functions)

Comment: @J.Delaney, thanks! So I've tried with $\text{exp}(-d/v)$, with $v=350$, but I'm still getting matrices which are not positive semidefinite.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. If you could share more details on your calculation it might be possible to see what is going wrong

Comment: @J.Delaney, you're right, my bad. Made a mistake in the way I was constructing the matrix from the pairwise correlations. Thank you very much!